# Square root of rank 1 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say we have vector $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
We can construct matrix $\operatorname{C} = cc^T$.

It's easy to see that

$$C \geq 0: x^T Cx = x^T cc^T x = (c^T x)^T c^Tx = (c^T x)\geq 0$$

Therefore, there will be a semi-positive defined square root of $\operatorname{C}$: $\operatorname{A}^2=C, \operatorname{A}\geq0$.

Is there any easy method to calculate $\operatorname{A}$ given a particular structure of $\operatorname{C}$?

Comment: Since the eigenvalues of $A$ are the square root of the eigenvalues of $C$, $A$ must be rank 1 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume $c\neq 0$ so that $c^Tc > 0$.

Since the eigenvalues of $A$ are the square root of the eigenvalues of $C$, $A$ must be rank 1 as well.

So, we want to find $a,b$ such that $A= ab^T$ and $A^2 = cc^T$.

Substituting, we have $A^2 = ab^Tab^T = (b^Ta) ab^T = cc^T$.

Letting $a=b=\alpha c$ with $\alpha \in \Bbb R$, we get $A^2 = \alpha^4(c^Tc)cc^T = \alpha^4(c^Tc)C$. Therefore, we want $\alpha=(c^Tc)^{-1/4}$.

Overall, we find that
$$A = \frac{cc^T}{\sqrt{c^Tc}},$$
is a square root of $C=cc^T$.